# Port Forwarding Security

Tags: python, security, port, password-protection, portforwarding

I have a Python program that runs on my Windows 7 computer which communicates with a Raspberry Pi over the internet through a port I opened with a Port Forwarding rule on my internet modem. 
I am concerned about a hacker getting through that open port and causing problems.

My question is:

Is there a way to password protect that port so anyone who tries to access that port is required to enter the correct password to get through to my Raspberry Pi?
If not, what other ways could I protect that open port?

Any help/advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off topic. You may want to move your post to http://security.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: Need anymore help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Right now I am following this tutorial to put a VPN on the Raspberry Pi. I hope that will result in the user needing to enter a password to access the Pi.    

http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing#awesm=~oBvYD8BOiTdCQN

Answer (score 3):

You cannot password protect a port. That concept is several layers up in the network stack and not something regular internet gear has anything to do with.

You'll have to add authentication at the service/application layer. Meaning, your Pi will have to demand authentication. Whether that's possible or not depends on what's running on it.

If that's not available, you'll need an intermediary. Either you set up a proxy in front of the Pi that can handle authentication; or you set up a VPN server instead of a simple forwarded port, which would put the authentication at the point of network access.

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively "password protect a port" via an SSH tunnel.

Instead of opening your application's port, you open TCP port 22 and run an SSH daemon. The SSH service can be protected by a password, passphrase, a key file or a combination thereof.

When you connect to SSH from Windows using PuTTY or Plink, you can specify that a local port on your Windows box is mapped to the port on your remote Raspberry Pi.

So rather than connecting to, say `203.0.113.0` on port 1234, you would connect to `127.0.0.1` on your Windows machine on port 1234 after establishing the SSH connection and this will route it through to the machine at the other end of the SSH tunnel.